# Angular: How to control Select element's "Size" attribute using typescript variables?

Tags: html, css, angular, html-select

I am trying to replace the **size="6"** with **size="this.groupsList.length"** but it's not working. How can this be done?

```
<select name="groups" size="6">
   <option *ngFor="let group of groupsList">{{group.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Background:

I am doing this because the select tag is providing its own scrollbar if the # of elements is > the "size", but since I need to use ngx-perfect-scrollbar instead, I need to change the "size" attribute dynamically. Since I am using ngx-perfect-scrollbar, I need to hide the select tag's scrollbar, but upon doing so it's also hiding some group names (if the "size" attribute is less than the length of groupsList.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do this:

```
<select name="groups" [attr.size]="groupsList.length">
   <option *ngFor="let group of groupsList">{{group.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I added the following to my .ts file :

```
const selectTag = document.getElementById('groupsListSelect');
selectTag.setAttribute("size",this.groupsList.length+"")
```

and added "id="groupsListSelect" in the html:

```
<select id="groupsListSelect" name="groups" size="1">
    <option *ngFor="let group of groupsList">{{group.name}}</option>
</select>
```

it overrides the size of 1 with the above typescript code just after groupsList has been initialized.